# Is there a function that I can use for catching these GET requests on php curl )

Tags: php, curl

I am specifically looking for a way to capture the request for webpages such as links or initial home page so that my application can capture and run the string through a set of case statements to find the correct data to return. I need to capture request like this.

1
GET http://www.w3.org/pub/WWW/TheProject.html HTTP/1.1

Comment: Describe your goal and *current code / usage* a bit more detailed. It's not clear how and where or why you want to "capture" something. E.g. have you tried simply wrapping your curl invocations in a helper function and interecept the requested URL there?

Comment: try to capture all GET \ responses (urls) from server

Comment: `w3.org` is not your server. Show your current code, and describe your question less vaguely.

Comment: i do POST action and can get response code 200 OK. after that while i debug process i see GET action on firebug debug screen.and i can not call that GET request from my curl php codes

Answer (score 0):

May be you are interested in [$_SERVER](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)